# Is there a way to transfer a book from an iPad back to iTunes?

Tags: itunes, ipad, ebook

I have an eBook that I downloaded and then manually synched to my iPad. I have managed to somehow delete the original file from my laptop, and so I cannot synch the book to my phone to read there. It no longer appears in my library in iTunes either. Is there a way to transfer the book from my iPad back to the iTunes library so that I can synch it to other devices?

Comment: Did you get the ebook from the iTunes store or somewhere else like Kindle?

Comment: depends what app you're reading it in - some can copy files directly to & from the Finder via iTunes. Marvin, GoodReader, Stanza, etc.

Comment: If it was synched to the iPad, doesn't that mean it was in iBooks?